# How to hide a field in a views row if the row is about content type article?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that is showing all my content types. What I want is to hide a certain field in its row if the content type on this particular views row has a content type of Article.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is using [Views Conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> ```
> Equal To
> Not Equal To
> Greater Than
> Less Than
> Empty
> Not Empty
> ```
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.
>
> ---
>
> How to use Views Conditional in your Views:
>   1. Create a view. Add some fields under "FIELDS".
>   2. Click on "ADD" next to fields. Scroll down to "Views: Views Conditional", probably found near the bottom of the list.
>   3. Add and configure fields...
>   4. Choose a field to run a condition against, and provide values accordingly.
>   5. Save, views conditional handles the logic and returns as specified.

For findout how it work  at [Views Conditional Module (Drupal 7 Tutorial) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIyZV_Hhccw)

Answer (score 0):

Add content type as a hidden field above the field you wish to hide. For the field you wish to hide rewrite the field so as to add a class, using the token for the hidden field (ie [hidden-[type] ), then target that via CSS (ie target hidden-article)